# Как убрать тег <p> из shortcode - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

В файле single.php вывожу дополнительные поля так

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Текст', true)); ?>
```

Т.е. в поле текст работают шорткоды, но есть одна проблема!

Я в админке, в дополнительном поле (Текст), пишу:

```
<a href="[short_code]">Привет мир</a>: <span class"new">Марс</span>
```

Вместо того, чтобы вывести все в одну строку, у меня тег `<a>` оборачивается тегом `<p>`.

Как его убрать? Но только из шорткода, ибо если убрать из всего контента, статьи сливаються в один сплошной текст.

Comment: А как вы убираете теги <p> из контента?

Comment: можно их так убрать  remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); но дело не в контенте, а именно в дополнительных полях, так как нужно убрать именно в них. Т.е в шорткоде которые выводиться в дополнительных полях. Так как без шорткода в ссылке, все идет в одну строку и нет тега <p>

Comment: Ну и вызовите remove wpautop перед apply_filters, а потом верните wpautop с помощью add_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');

Comment: Спасибо ! Сделал хитрей :) <?php echo apply_filters(remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop'), get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Текст', true)); ?>

Comment: Так неправильно. Apply filters получает результат работы remove filter, а это true или false

Comment: Не понял проблемы, у меня все работает, в контенте есть тег <p> в доп полях нет. Что может произойти в данной конструкции ?

Comment: Не знаю, как оно работает, не видя всего кода. Но. Apply filters точно не работает, потому что у нее первый параметр не имя фильтра, а true. Кроме того, не возвращается wpautop. Может, он и не нужен, но...

Comment: Работает, скорее всего, потому, что таким образом хитроумно отключили aplly filters))))

Comment: Отладчик включите и посмотрите)))

Comment: Ну главное что проблема решена !  А то я с этим шорт кодом уже 2 тягаюсь, то там что не то то сям :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удалите фильтр wpautop перед обработкой вашего поля и не забудьте его вернуть назад:

```
remove_filter ( 'the_content', 'wpautop');
echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Текст', true));
add_filter ( 'the_content', 'wpautop');
```

То, что написано в вашем комментарии и потом скопировано в другой ответ - типичный пример плохого кода, который работает кое-как. Поясняю.

Вы решили проблему такой строкой:

```
<?php echo apply_filters(remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop'), get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Текст', true)); ?>
```

Что тут происходит, на самом деле? `remove_filter()` возвращает только true или false (почитайте описание в codex). Дальше вы делаете вызов

```
apply_filters(true, get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Текст', true));
```

WordPress молча прожевывает эту бредятину, apply_filters ничего не делает, и возвращает то, что было в `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Текст', true)`. По сути, вы просто выкинули apply_filters из вашего кода таким хитроумным костылем. Вот эквивалент вашей "хитрой" строки:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Текст', true); ?>
```

Так что предложенная вами строка работает на 1/3 от написанного  в ней кода и поставит в тупик любого другого программиста, не знакомого с текущим обсуждением. Так делать не надо.

Я с самого начала хотел предложить просто убрать apply_filters() (и обернуть в do_shortcode() ), но, поскольку у вас еще какая-то еще работа с контентом, а кода целиком я не вижу, то дал предложение с фильтрами.

**UPDATE.** Я свел все варианты, обсужденные в ответе и в комментариях, на [странице моего тестового сайта](http://test.kagg.eu/so707342/).

Страница имеет собственный php-шаблон. Код этого шаблона:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: 707342
*/

echo 'shortcode: ' . do_shortcode('[short_code]') . '<br>';

echo 'apply_filters: ' . apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Текст', true)) . '<br>';

echo 'apply_filters(remove_filter: ' . apply_filters(remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop'), get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Текст', true)) . '<br>';

echo 'post_meta: ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Текст', true) . '<br>';

echo 'Правильный вариант (remove - apply - add): ';
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Текст', true) );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
echo '<br>';

echo 'Правильный вариант (do_shortcode): ';
echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Текст', true) );
echo '<br>';
```

В functions.php:

```
function test_short_code() {
    return 'https://google.com';
}
add_shortcode('short_code','test_short_code');
```

Как видим, вариант apply_filter(remove_filter не работает. Ровно потому, что я написал вышел - он просто возвращает get_post_meta.

Comment: В вашей предложенной альтернативе, <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Текст', true); ?> не будет работать шорткод ! в дополнительных полях. Так как вами предложенный код у меня находися в полях где шорткод не нужен Т.е так выводяться поля (где он не применяеться)

Comment: Говоря - убрать aplly_filters, я имел ввиду не просто убрать (понятно, что не будет выполняться шорткод), а обернуть в do_shortcode. Сейчас дополню ответ с примером на тестовом сайте.

Comment: Отличный пример !

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.